# Sample conditional distribution for three variables

Tags: r, conditional-statements, distribution, sample

I would like to create a setup where the dependent variable `y` and two explanatory variables `x` and `z` with specified conditional correlations `r_yx`and `r_zx` and `r_yz` that I can vary myself.

```
r_yx <- 0.9
r_zx <- -0.5
r_yz <- 0.9

n <- 10000

x <- rnorm(n, mean = 0, sd = 1)

y <- r_yx*x + rnorm(n, mean = 0, sd = 1)
```

Question 1: How can I now create `x` so that it the correlation with `y` is `r_yx = .9` and the correlation with `z = -.5`?

Question 2: Also checking `cor(y,x)` shows that it is not that close to 0.9. How can I set it correctly?

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to generate random samples that have an *exact* correlation, but you can get pretty close. For positive correlations with `x`, just add some noise to `x`. The better you want the correlation, the smaller you make the `sd`.

We can get fairly close to 0.9 and -0.5 like this

```r
n <- 10000

set.seed(1)

x <- rnorm(n, mean = 0, sd = 1)

y <- x + rnorm(n, 0, sd = 0.5)

z <- -x + rnorm(n, 0, 1.75)

cor(x, y)
#> [1] 0.8986359

cor(x, z)
#> [1] -0.4983418
```

However, you cannot independently change the correlation of y to z if you have already fixed their correlation to x. In the extreme case, if y's correlation with x was 1, then y would be identical to x, and would therefore have to have the same correlation to z as x did.

<sup>Created on 2022-06-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>